# Pipe into if statement?

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

I'm writing a bash script. I have a series of pipes working to get all the branches on a git repository:

```
git ls-remote $1 'refs/heads/*' \
  | rev \
  | cut -d'/' -f1 \
  | rev \
  | if [ -z $2 ]
      then
        echo {}
      else
        echo {} > $2
    fi
```

Currently the if statement part of this doesn't work properly. What do I replace `{}` with to make this work?

Comment: Make it work how exactly? To copy standard input to standard output, use `cat`, not `echo`.

Comment: And quote your variables, `"$1"` and `"$2"`.

Comment: @tripleee currently it prints {} not the result from previous pipe.

Comment: If you mean the standard input received by the `if` statement, ... Sorry, I can't think of any simpler way to say it. I think you want `cat`.

Comment: You might also want to replace the `rev | cut | rev` with `sed 's~.*/~~'`

Comment: Similar: [Conditional pipeline](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/38310)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To copy standard input to standard output, use `cat`, not `echo`.

```
git ls-remote "$1" 'refs/heads/*' |
sed 's~.*/~~' |
if [ -z "$2" ]
  then
    cat
  else
    cat > "$2"
fi
```

Notice also the proper use of quotes and the placement of the pipes so you can avoid the backslashes. The use of `sed` is a very minor optimization but I also find it clearer than the double `rev` around a `cut` (provided you grok regex). You could also use `awk -F/ '{ print $NF }'` (but then that requires you to grok Awk).

You could avoid the `cat` by doing this instead;

```
${2+exec >"$2"}
git ls-remote "$1" | sed 's~.*/~~'
```

(The failure if you pass in an empty string as the second argument should at least be more explicit, if not necessarily more helpful, than with `[ -z`, which fails to distinguish between an unset and an empty value.)

Comment: Yes, it also protects any wildcard characters in the values from being expanded by the shell; and newline could still be included in the values, although that woud be a rather pathological corner case here.

Answer (score 5):

You can just replace `{}` syntax you're trying to use with `cat` since you're trying to read from `stdin`:

```
git ls-remote $1 'refs/heads/*' \
  | rev \
  | cut -d'/' -f1 \
  | rev \
  | if [ -z $2 ]
      then
        cat
      else
        cat > $2
    fi
```

**Update**: no subshell is needed, thanks [@tripleee](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/19240/tripleee).